# на локальном прикрепляется файл в форму, на удаленном нет

Tags: php

Вот ошибка:

```
Warning:  file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in 
/home/host1449451/transkribator.ru/htdocs/form/post.php on line 44





$from = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$to = "***@yandex.ru";
$subject = "Пупкин";

$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['photo']
['tmp_name'])));
$filename = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
$filetype = $_FILES['photo']['type'];

$boundary = md5(date('r', time()));

$headers = "From: " . $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"_1_$boundary\"";

$message="
--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_2_$boundary\"

--_2_$boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

$message

--_2_$boundary--
--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: \"$filetype\"; name=\"$filename\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment

$attachment
--_1_$boundary--";

 mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: очевидно, что вы передаете в `file_get_contents` пустую строку, или null

Comment: это очевидно, но на локальном прикрепляя файл, он прикрепляется, а на удаленном - не прикрепляется. Вот в чем вопрос

Comment: вот здесь: http://form.transkribator.ru/

Comment: Сделайте `var_dump($_FILES)` и посмотрите, что в нем. Если все ок - посмотрите в логи веб-сервера

Comment: ошибки аплоада смотрите. мб размер фото велик, места может на сервере не хватать и т.п.

Comment: var_dump($_FILES) - на локальном - все приаттачивается, на удаленном - пустой массив

Comment: @teran - файлик для пробы весом 10кб

Comment: вы уверены что на удаленном серверу, у инпут с файлом имя (`name`) есть и он передается на сервер? посмотрите в браузере, шлет ли он контент картинки вообще в инструментах ф12-сеть при отправке формы.

Comment: нет, на удаленном не шлет

Comment: шлет на локальном

Comment: ну дак формы отправки то идентичные?

Comment: конечно, в том и вопрос, что все одинаково, но на локальном все хорошо, на удаленном ничего. Такая же проблема была и с PHPMailer - на локальном шлет - на удаленном не шлет. Двое суток угробил

Comment: ну вот и решился вопрос ценою 2 дня жизни... потом напишу